requestFocus() works for Android emulator but not for web
This is a piece of Flutter code. For Android emulator the "move focus" button works very well, input 1 and 2 take turns getting focus. But for chrome(web), the "move focus" button doesn't work. The focus always stays on input 1. I can't figure out why. (Flutter version: 3.19.5. flutter doctor -v  shows "No issues found!")
class FocusTestRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const FocusTestRoute({super.key});

  @override
  State<FocusTestRoute> createState() => _FocusTestRouteState();
}

class _FocusTestRouteState extends State<FocusTestRoute> {
  FocusNode fn1 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode fn2 = FocusNode();
  FocusScopeNode? fcn;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            focusNode: fn1,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: "input 1",
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            focusNode: fn2,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: "input 2",
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      fcn ??= FocusScope.of(context);
                      if (fcn?.focusedChild == fn1){
                        fcn?.requestFocus(fn2);
                      }else{
                        fcn?.requestFocus(fn1);
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text('Move focus'),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


If you check the fcn?.children or fcn?.children.length, you will find out that you have three FocusNodes (I think the ElevatedButton also has focus*), then, when you click this button, the focus is changed, Therefore the condition fn1.hasFocus is always wrong and the else statement is changing the focus to the first input (fn1).
if (fn1.hasFocus) {
  fcn?.requestFocus(fn2);
} else {
  fcn?.requestFocus(fn1);
}

Since using a Focus widget and disabling the focus don't work either (I guess), a quick solution is to keep the focused node id in a variable:
int focusedNode = 0; // in your widget

and change the statement like this:
// inside onPressed
if (focusedNode == 0) {
  focusedNode = 1;
  fcn?.requestFocus(fn2);
} else {
  focusedNode = 0;
  fcn?.requestFocus(fn1);
}

You may want to use keys instead of the int value or you may find a better solution.
* I set the property focusNode for ElevatedButton and it has the same key as the third element, but when I click the button, it doesn't change. Even disabling the button focus didn't work.
